# Node.js - How to set up a server on my local machine and allow someone to access it(for testing)

Tags: node.js, testing

I am writing a node.js app and need to get a friend to help test it for me(at a different location). Can I set something up on my local machine to allow him to access it? I tried Googling but found little help.

Could someone please tell me how? I realize this is a terrible idea for production purposes, but I'm only planning on using it for testing as the budget for this project is a little tight.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I guess the answer to your question would be "Yes."  There's no reason why you can't run node.js on your computer.

Comment: Then could you please explain how or point me to a good article/tutorial?

Comment: I've never actually installed or used node.js, though a quick Google search for "installing node.js" turned up some promising results.  I guess your first step will be learning how to install and use it.

Comment: I have it installed. It's quite easy to set up a localhost, but that can only be accessed from my computer

Comment: This question isn't specific to node - you just want to host a web server on your local machine which is visible to the outside world. Any number of articles will tell you how to do that including [this](http://superuser.com/questions/21931/how-can-i-make-my-home-pc-a-web-server) one.

Comment: It sounds like the code itself is working and you're having issues making it accessible to another computer.  Any number of details can affect that.  (Firewalls, routers, subnets, etc., etc.)  That may be more on-topic for something like SuperUser than StackOverflow.

Comment: @TechEpic , all you need is your computer should be accesible from on the internet. once you achive that then your friend or anyone can access your node app as http://192.78.989.1:8080  or whatever port you are runnng

Answer (score 5):

First of all you should bind your node http(s) server to your public IP, for example:

```
var http = require("http");
// ...
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    // ...
}).listen(PORT, null); // passing null or nothing as the second argument, will bind the http server to all interfaces.
```

Next, if you're behind a router/firewall you should add a route to your computer (on your local network) on the port that your node server is listening on.

Also you should have a static IP address or use dynamic DNS, so your friend will be able to reach your computer.